# Question about one moment in proof connected with squaring and sums

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading an article about derivation of least squares estimator and I can't figure out one thing. Namely, asuuming that $q=\bar{y}-a-b\bar{x}$ how does the equality

$$  \sum[q-(b x_i-y_i)]^2=nq^2+\sum (b x_i-y_i)^2           $$
hold?
I know that we are using the formula $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ but where is the $2ab$ expression? I don't see that it is equal to zero.

Link to the article: http://www.economics.hawaii.edu/research/workingpapers/88-98/WP_96-11.pdf (the end of second page)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $q$ implicitely depends on $b,x_i,y_i$, there might be some simplifications (I did not make the computation).

Comment: I have also thought this way, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, the paper uses uppercase $Y$ and $X$ and lowercase $y$ and $x$ to mean different things.

> Further defining $y_i$ and $x_i$ as deviations of $Y_i$ and $X_i$ from their means

That is, $y_i = Y_i - \bar{Y}$ and $x_i = X_i - \bar{X}$.

The cross term vanishes since $\sum(bx_i - y_i) = b \sum (X_i - \bar{X}) + \sum (Y_i - \bar{Y}) = 0$.